# How to use a different databases depending on login status in Django?

Tags: django

Basically, to not have to worry about replication lag if a user is logged in, we want them to read/write to the master; but if the user is not logged in, we want them to read from the replica and write to the master. Is this possible using Django routers?

Comment: Sounds like a bad solution. It won't scale and it's very complex. How about having two different WSGI projects running a different settings.py and then redirecting to different websites depending on login? (master.xxx.com, replica.xxx.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be bad practice, but at any point within your code, as long as you are using Django >= 1.2, with the `using()` method and `using` keyword, you have total control over which database select your QuerySets and do your saves and deletes.

For example, for a QuerySet:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.using('replica').all()
```

or saving an object:

```
>>> my_object.save(using='master')
```

So you could always do something like this in a view:

```
query_set = MyModel.objects.all()

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    query_set = query_set.using('master')
```

But this could get very cumbersome and should you decide to go along this road, you should seek a more elegant ways to mitigate it. [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/), [middlewares](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/middleware/) and/or [model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/) come to mind.

See [Manually selecting a database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database) from the Django documentation.

Comment: Did you use this method? Can you share it please?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MasterSlaveRouter(object):
    """A router that sets up a simple master/slave configuration"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all read operations to a random slave"
        return random.choice(['slave1','slave2'])

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all write operations to the master"
        return 'master'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        "Allow any relation between two objects in the db pool"
        db_list = ('master','slave1','slave2')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Explicitly put all models on all databases."
        return True
```

*From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/)*

This can be if you really want to do it as an exercise, but I would not recommend it if this is going into production.

You are asking your database to do the replication for you, which is the right way to go about it.

Then in your application you are basically saying that you want to jump in the middle of this replication and write to the slave and then read from the master; in other words you are trying to use replication the same way as you would a cluster.  This can only lead to bad things down the road; concurrency for one is going to be a problem. Connection pooling another, and data integrity a third.

A different approach to decrease the response time - if a user has an account, load their information in a fast cache backend like redis or couchdb - depending on your preference of key/value vs. document based stores.

For guest users, since they will not be doing as many writes as reads this would reduce the load from your db a bit; not to mention improve the performance for registered users.

Comment: You're never writing directly to the slave with that example Router. You're always writing to the master, and letting the database do its own replication to the slave. The replication could potentially be delayed though, which is the problem that Chewie wants to avoid. Unfortunately I don't think Django routers provide any way around it currently.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yes. Take a look at the [django-multi-db](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multidb-router) project. It provides a simple MasterSlaveRouter which is almost identical to the one given in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/). It also provides a PinningMasterSlaveRouter though, which addresses your exact problem. From their documentation:

> In some applications, the lag between the master receiving a write and its replication to the slaves is enough to cause inconsistency for the end user. For example, imagine a scenario with 1 second of replication lag. If a user makes a forum post (to the master) and then is redirected to a fully-rendered view of it (from a slave) 500ms later, the view will fail. If this is a problem in your application, consider using multidb.PinningMasterSlaveRouter. This router works in combination with multidb.middleware.PinningRouterMiddleware to assure that, after writing to the default database, future reads from the same user agent are directed to the default database for a configurable length of time.

The PiningMasterSlaveRouter will only select the master for a read if it thinks a database write has been done during that request. That's probably a better strategy that always reading from the master for logged in users, but if you're sure that's what you want then it's still possible to achieve with a little bit of additional middleware:

```
class SelectMasterForLoggedInUsers(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            response._db_write = True
```